# Scroll Bug in iPhone

Tags: javascript, scroll

I work on a vueJs page. There are several tables can scroll horizontal. This tables make page's height more than viewport's height. I can scroll Horizontal table and scroll Vertial page without bug. but in iPhone, If touch on table, i can not scroll Vertial page(other sections scrolled fine).

Answer (score 0):

You can try contain your table with another div, like:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner table"></div>
</div>
```

and styles:

```
.outer {
  overflow: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.inner {
  height: calc(100% + 1px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the answer. i found the page has wraper with style `height: 100%`. this leads `body`'s height is equal to viewport's height, but the section contain table's height is great than viewport. 
In ios, we should two fingers to scroll a local roll.
The final solution is remove the style `height:100%` on wrap